# Vue3 Dockerize - Can't open running docker vue app in my browser

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 app and dockerize it with this files:

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /var/www/html/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
EXPOSE 5173
CMD npm run dev
```

Docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  vue:
    container_name: vue
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/app
      - /var/www/html/app/node_modules
```

After **docker-compose -f Docker-compose.dev.yml up** command,

container ran perfectly,

But when I try to open http://localhost:5173/ in my browser, nothing happend!

---

**FIXED**

I need to added host: true config to vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  server: {
    host: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Even if this is not the cause of the issue, the two `volumes:` lines in your docker-compose.yml file are non-standard, in general they can be removed and replaced with a `COPY . ./` line *after* `RUN npm i`

Comment: In any case, you should check that your Vue3 app indeed listens to the port 5173 for the **0.0.0.0** special IP address (not just localhost).

Comment: Have you check the container logs?

Comment: Log's is ok, app run on 5173 in container, and I used volumes instead of copy because of want to develop this app

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing `CMD npm run dev` with `CMD npm run dev --host 0.0.0.0` in your Dockerfile?